# why is this snippet working when the positions should be the other way around?

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

```
 <h1 id='title2'>news,tips and more!!</h1>
<button class="button" type="button">Contact us!</button>

    #title2{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 560px;
  color: greenyellow;
}


.button {
   background-color: greenyellow;
   color: black;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 97px;
   left: 200px;

}
```

I'm just wondering why this works when position absolute you can only make it work by having position relative as parent?

Comment: _It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block._ [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: `position:absolute` does NOT require a relative parent

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood the relationship between `position: absolute` and `position: relative`.

---

When you absolutely position an element, it is positioned with respect to its nearest *ancestor* (not parent) which is *positioned*.

An element is *positioned* if the value of its `position` property is **not** `static`.

If there is no such element, then it is positioned with respect to the browser viewport. (This is what is happening in your example).

---

`position: relative` is the only positioning scheme which leaves the element in *normal flow*. If there is no `left`, `top`, etc property then it won't change how that element is laid out at all.

This makes it a popular way to make an element *positioned* so that a descendant that is absolutely positioned is positioned with respect to it.

---

Since you almost never want to position an element with respect to the viewport (and if you do then you might want to think about grid or flexbox layouts instead of positioning) it is *usual* to have a close ancestor that is `position: relative` to control where the absolutely positioned element goes.

i.e. it is a useful tool that you will want to use in 9/10 cases to get the effect you want, not a requirement.